# Holding a static int through software reboot

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a department store management system for a project. I am managing a range of objects and I want to have unique IDs for all of them, so that no two objects have the same ID.

For that purpose I want to hold an int symbolizing the last ID used in the program.

I know I can't use static int as it resets when the program restarts...

I thought about saving it to the disk on shut down but that seems not elegant to me. And so I wanted to ask, is there a better way to store the last ID in a way that I can use it when the software reboots?

Thank you!

Comment: Google for 'database'...

Comment: The hashcode has a pretty good chance of being unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the .NET Settings to store the variable per appliction or even per user.

1) Go to the Project properties -> Settings and create a new LastID variable of the type int

[image]

2) Then you can use this variable from the code

```
Settings.Default.LastID = lastID;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

The saved value will be available after the application restarts

```
lastID = Settings.Default.LastID;
```

Comment: That is working perfectly! I just wanted to point out that the scope has to be "user" in order to edit the setting.  Thanks!